# Force on plates of a capacitor, connected to battery,with inserted dielectric slab

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, dielectric

[Referring to this question,](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262484/force-between-plates-of-a-capacitor-with-dielectric-a-battery?newreg=6b80e2cc28e3497487a3b0f1b8d243a6) I had a confusion regarding the electric field strength between the capacitor plates. Since we have a constant potential difference across the plates and a constant distance between the plates, we get

E = V/d (constant)        (1)

Also, we have E (by one plate) = σ/2(epsilon nought) = q/2A(epsilon nought)

As from the referred solution, it said that the electric field for a solid dielectric slab is not dependent on the dielectric constant K.
but, q/2a(epsilon nought) turns to Kq/2A(epsilon nought) on insertion of dielectric, therefore the electric field changes, contradicting (1).

Where am I thinking it wrong? I am still not convinced the force between the plates increases by a product of K^2. Please help.

Comment: What is wrong with the answer of rodrigo in the linked question?

Comment: @trula it doesnt address the doubt that should we use the permittivity of the dielectric or that of vacuum